# How to add popup overlay in next js redirected url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I am creating one url shortener , I want to do something like Call To Action on target urls page. Tech stack :NextJs, Tailwind , NodeJs , Express

Like this kind of:
[image]

Please Help if anyone knows! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use popover for the above feature, check it out at: https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/popover/. Unlike the modal, the popover will not disappear with a click, it only shows or hides when the code specifies it.
Hope it helps!